# PyQT5: QCheckBoxes act like radio boxes

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a few checkboxes that are supposed to display different areas on a map. When I click one of them--it works perfectly well, but when more than one is pressed they begin to act like regular radio boxes (i.e. replacing the old areas by the new areas; not displaying both). I'm sure the issue is in `drawObjects`, but I can't figure it out. Does anyone know how I can fix it?

```
for i in range(len(self.floorMap.classes)):
   self.sem_index.insert(i, QCheckBox(self.floorMap.classes[i]))
   sem_label_group.addButton(self.sem_index[i])
   sem_label_box.addWidget(self.sem_index[i])
   self.sem_index[i].stateChanged.connect(self.check_clicked)

def check_clicked(self):

    rbtn = self.sender()
    text = rbtn.text()

    if rbtn.isChecked() == True:
        self.semMapID = self.floorMap.classes.index(text)

        obj = self.floorMap.rooms[self.currentRoom].objects[self.currentObjInd]
        self.drawObjects(self.semMapID, obj.id)

 def drawObjects(self, semLabel, objId=-1):
    clr = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(self.floorMap.classes)))
    self.drawn_map = self.highlight_map.copy()
    noDrawInd = len(self.floorMap.classes) + 1
    allDrawInd = len(self.floorMap.classes)
    if semLabel != noDrawInd:
        for roomID, room in enumerate(self.floorMap.rooms):
            for obj in room.objects:
                if (obj.semLabel == semLabel) or (semLabel == allDrawInd):
                    color = 255 * clr[obj.semLabel, :3]
                    x1, y1, x2, y2 = obj.position
                    if (objId == obj.id) and (roomID == self.currentRoom):
                        cv2.rectangle(self.drawn_map, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, -1)
                    else:
                        cv2.rectangle(self.drawn_map, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 1)
    image = QImage(
        self.drawn_map,
        self.drawn_map.shape[1],
        self.drawn_map.shape[0],
        self.drawn_map.shape[1] * 3,
        QImage.Format_RGB888,
    )
    self.edit_pix = QPixmap(image)
    self.main_image.img = self.edit_pix
    self.main_image.setPixmap(self.edit_pix)
```

Edit: Updated without the lamda

Comment: First of all, the lambda is wrong, as `i` will **always** be the *last* value in the for loop, so it should be `self.sem_index[i].toggled.connect(lambda state, i=i: self.check_clicked(self.sem_index[i]))`. But since you're not actually using that value, and you need to check for *all* checkboxes, you need to *iterate* through them every time you are going to redraw, meaning that you can also lose the lambda at all and just connect to the function.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you for explaining! I updated the post.

Comment: As said, you have to *cycle* through all checkboxes and create the new map items accordingly. Unfortunately, your code is insufficient to really be able to help you, so I suggest you to provide a valid [mre] in order to get proper answers. As a side note, `if rbtn.isChecked() == True:` is pointless: just do `if rbtn.isChecked():`